# Right and left alignment in enumerated lists LaTex

Tags: latex

So for this piece of code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[Komutativnost] $(a+b) = (b+a)$
\item[Asocijativnost] $a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c$
\item[Distributivnost] $a*(b+c) = (a*c) + (b*c)$
\end{enumerate}
```

I get this result:

[image]

How can I left/right align the item title and left/right align item text.

Comment: Can you specify, what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: I do not understand what kind of align you want, but enumerate is for numeral items. To add a textual description of the item, use `\begin{description}...\end{description}`

Comment: @AlainMerigot yep that works for me now. I found one solution like this:
\begin{description} [align = left/right]

Answer (score 3):

*As usual*, if you do not add your preamble, it is difficult to say what is right or wrong ([**MWE**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)).

The `enumerate` environment is meant to produce numbered lists; if you want pointed lists or other effects you can use `itemize` or `description` instead (as in the comment by Alain).

I wrote to post your preamble because I've been doing LaTeX for 10 years now and I have no idea how `\begin{description}[align=left]` could ever work.

I will try to give you two "semantically decent" basic alternatives whose outputs differ almost only for indentation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% first way:
\begin{description}
    \item[Komutativnost] $(a+b) = (b+a)$
    \item[Asocijativnost] $a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c$
    \item[Distributivnost] $a*(b+c) = (a*c) + (b*c)$
\end{description}

% second way:
\begin{itemize}
    \item[] Komutativnost $(a+b) = (b+a)$
    \item[] Asocijativnost $a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c$
    \item[] Distributivnost $a*(b+c) = (a*c) + (b*c)$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[This article](https://texblog.org/2008/10/16/lists-enumerate-itemize-description-and-how-to-change-them/) may also help understanding.